# How to build executable jar file for an Apache Derby database application using Hibernate and developed in NetBeans?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, netbeans, build

I've tried to clean and build my project, but when I double-click on the executable jar file nothing happens. I have these settings enabled:
[image]

This is essentially an inventory manager application with an embedded Apache Derby database developed using Hibernate within the NetBeans IDE. 
Here are my libraries:

[image]

And here is the folder structure:

[image]

When I run the following command `jar tf filename.jar` in the cmd.exe:

```
C:\Projects\InternalAssessment_Hibernated\dist>jar tf InternalAssessment.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
DAO/
classes/
delivery/
delivery/view/
internalassessment/
main/
main/view/
miscellaneous/
miscellaneous/view/
partner/
partner/view/
report/
report/view/
setlimit/
setlimit/view/
stock/
stock/view/
DAO/AbstractModel.class
DAO/AdvicenoteModel.class
DAO/CategoryModel.class
DAO/HibernateUtil.class
DAO/ItemModel.class
DAO/Ledger.class
DAO/PartnerModel.class
DAO/TransactionModel.class
classes/Advicenote.class
classes/Advicenote.hbm.xml
classes/Categories.class
classes/Categories.hbm.xml
classes/Items.class
classes/Items.hbm.xml
classes/Limit.class
classes/Limit.hbm.xml
classes/Partner.class
classes/Partner.hbm.xml
classes/Transactions.class
classes/Transactions.hbm.xml
delivery/view/Delivery$1.class
delivery/view/Delivery$2.class
delivery/view/Delivery$3.class
delivery/view/Delivery$4.class
delivery/view/Delivery$5.class
delivery/view/Delivery$6.class
delivery/view/Delivery$7.class
delivery/view/Delivery.class
delivery/view/Selection$1.class
delivery/view/Selection$2.class
delivery/view/Selection$3.class
delivery/view/Selection$4.class
delivery/view/Selection.class
delivery/view/Transfer$1.class
delivery/view/Transfer$2.class
delivery/view/Transfer$3.class
delivery/view/Transfer$4.class
delivery/view/Transfer$5.class
delivery/view/Transfer$6.class
delivery/view/Transfer$7.class
delivery/view/Transfer.class
hibernate.cfg.xml
internalassessment/Webp.net-resizeimage (4).png
internalassessment/about.png
internalassessment/add_database.png
internalassessment/answers.png
internalassessment/banner.png
internalassessment/conference_call.png
internalassessment/database.png
internalassessment/delete_database.png
internalassessment/empty_filter.png
internalassessment/engflag.png
internalassessment/external.png
internalassessment/hibernate.png
internalassessment/high_priority.png
internalassessment/hunflag.png
internalassessment/in_transit.png
internalassessment/internal.png
internalassessment/list.png
internalassessment/netbeans.png
internalassessment/search.png
internalassessment/shipped.png
internalassessment/sms.png
internalassessment/synchronize.png
internalassessment/todo_list.png
internalassessment/view_details.png
main/view/Bundle.properties
main/view/Bundle_hu_HU.properties
main/view/MainMenu$1.class
main/view/MainMenu$FormListener.class
main/view/MainMenu.class
miscellaneous/view/Contents$1$1.class
miscellaneous/view/Contents$1.class
miscellaneous/view/Contents.class
miscellaneous/view/Tutorial$1$1.class
miscellaneous/view/Tutorial$1.class
miscellaneous/view/Tutorial.class
partner/view/AddPartner$1$1.class
partner/view/AddPartner$1.class
partner/view/AddPartner$FormListener.class
partner/view/AddPartner.class
partner/view/ModifyPartner$1$1.class
partner/view/ModifyPartner$1.class
partner/view/ModifyPartner$FormListener.class
partner/view/ModifyPartner.class
partner/view/PartnerView$1.class
partner/view/PartnerView$FormListener.class
partner/view/PartnerView.class
report/view/ReportView$1.class
report/view/ReportView$FormListener.class
report/view/ReportView$TableModel.class
report/view/ReportView.class
setlimit/view/LimitMessage$1.class
setlimit/view/LimitMessage.class
setlimit/view/SetQunatityLimit$1.class
setlimit/view/SetQunatityLimit$2.class
setlimit/view/SetQunatityLimit$3.class
setlimit/view/SetQunatityLimit.class
stock/view/AddCategory$1$1.class
stock/view/AddCategory$1.class
stock/view/AddCategory$FormListener.class
stock/view/AddCategory.class
stock/view/AddItem$1$1.class
stock/view/AddItem$1.class
stock/view/AddItem$FormListener.class
stock/view/AddItem.class
stock/view/CategoryView$1.class
stock/view/CategoryView$FormListener.class
stock/view/CategoryView.class
stock/view/ModifyCategory$1$1.class
stock/view/ModifyCategory$1.class
stock/view/ModifyCategory$FormListener.class
stock/view/ModifyCategory.class
stock/view/ModifyItem$1$1.class
stock/view/ModifyItem$1.class
stock/view/ModifyItem$FormListener.class
stock/view/ModifyItem.class
stock/view/StockView$1.class
stock/view/StockView$2.class
stock/view/StockView$FormListener.class
stock/view/StockView$ItemAndQuantity.class
stock/view/StockView.class
```

But when I try to extract the manifest `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` the contents aren't displayed:

```
C:\Projects\InternalAssessment_Hibernated\dist>jar tf InternalAssessment.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

C:\Projects\InternalAssessment_Hibernated\dist>
```

I don't know what could be wrong with my application, **any help would be appriciated!** It's my first time using apache Derby and Hibernate, so I am essentially clueless.

Also, here is my project.properties file, I hope it will help:

```
annotation.processing.enabled=true
annotation.processing.enabled.in.editor=false
annotation.processing.processor.options=-Aeclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory=false
annotation.processing.processors.list=
annotation.processing.run.all.processors=true
annotation.processing.source.output=${build.generated.sources.dir}/ap-source-output
application.title=InternalAssessment
application.vendor=Méri Marcell
auxiliary.org-netbeans-spi-editor-hints-projects.perProjectHintSettingsFile=nbproject/cfg_hints.xml
build.classes.dir=${build.dir}/classes
build.classes.excludes=**/*.java,**/*.form
# This directory is removed when the project is cleaned:
build.dir=build
build.generated.dir=${build.dir}/generated
build.generated.sources.dir=${build.dir}/generated-sources
# Only compile against the classpath explicitly listed here:
build.sysclasspath=ignore
build.test.classes.dir=${build.dir}/test/classes
build.test.results.dir=${build.dir}/test/results
# Uncomment to specify the preferred debugger connection transport:
#debug.transport=dt_socket
debug.classpath=\
    ${run.classpath}
debug.modulepath=\
    ${run.modulepath}
debug.test.classpath=\
    ${run.test.classpath}
debug.test.modulepath=\
    ${run.test.modulepath}
# Files in build.classes.dir which should be excluded from distribution jar
dist.archive.excludes=
# This directory is removed when the project is cleaned:
dist.dir=dist
dist.jar=${dist.dir}/InternalAssessment.jar
dist.javadoc.dir=${dist.dir}/javadoc
dist.jlink.dir=${dist.dir}/jlink
dist.jlink.output=${dist.jlink.dir}/InternalAssessment
endorsed.classpath=
excludes=
file.reference.antlr-2.7.7.jar=lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar
file.reference.byte-buddy-1.9.5.jar=lib/byte-buddy-1.9.5.jar
file.reference.classmate-1.3.4.jar=lib/classmate-1.3.4.jar
file.reference.derby.jar=lib/derby.jar
file.reference.dom4j-2.1.1.jar=lib/dom4j-2.1.1.jar
file.reference.FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar=lib/FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar
file.reference.hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar=lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar
file.reference.hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar=lib/hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar
file.reference.istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar=lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar
file.reference.jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar=lib/jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar
file.reference.javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar=lib/javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar
file.reference.javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar=lib/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
file.reference.javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar=lib/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar
file.reference.jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar=lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
file.reference.jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar=lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar
file.reference.jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar=lib/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar
file.reference.jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar=lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar
file.reference.stax-ex-1.8.jar=lib/stax-ex-1.8.jar
file.reference.txw2-2.3.1.jar=lib/txw2-2.3.1.jar
includes=**
jar.archive.disabled=${jnlp.enabled}
jar.compress=false
jar.index=${jnlp.enabled}
javac.classpath=\
    ${file.reference.FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.antlr-2.7.7.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.byte-buddy-1.9.5.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.classmate-1.3.4.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.derby.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.dom4j-2.1.1.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.stax-ex-1.8.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.txw2-2.3.1.jar}
# Space-separated list of extra javac options
javac.compilerargs=
javac.deprecation=false
javac.external.vm=true
javac.modulepath=
javac.processormodulepath=
javac.processorpath=\
    ${javac.classpath}:\
    ${libs.eclipselink.classpath}
javac.source=11
javac.target=11
javac.test.classpath=\
    ${javac.classpath}:\
    ${build.classes.dir}
javac.test.modulepath=\
    ${javac.modulepath}
javac.test.processorpath=\
    ${javac.test.classpath}
javadoc.additionalparam=
javadoc.author=false
javadoc.encoding=${source.encoding}
javadoc.html5=false
javadoc.noindex=false
javadoc.nonavbar=false
javadoc.notree=false
javadoc.private=false
javadoc.splitindex=true
javadoc.use=true
javadoc.version=false
javadoc.windowtitle=
# The jlink additional root modules to resolve
jlink.additionalmodules=
# The jlink additional command line parameters
jlink.additionalparam=
jlink.launcher=true
jlink.launcher.name=InternalAssessment
jnlp.codebase.type=no.codebase
jnlp.descriptor=application
jnlp.enabled=false
jnlp.mixed.code=default
jnlp.offline-allowed=false
jnlp.signed=false
jnlp.signing=
jnlp.signing.alias=
jnlp.signing.keystore=
main.class=main.view.MainMenu
# Optional override of default Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase attribute identifying the locations where your signed RIA is expected to be found.
manifest.custom.application.library.allowable.codebase=
# Optional override of default Caller-Allowable-Codebase attribute identifying the domains from which JavaScript code can make calls to your RIA without security prompts.
manifest.custom.caller.allowable.codebase=
# Optional override of default Codebase manifest attribute, use to prevent RIAs from being repurposed
manifest.custom.codebase=
# Optional override of default Permissions manifest attribute (supported values: sandbox, all-permissions)
manifest.custom.permissions=
manifest.file=manifest.mf
meta.inf.dir=${src.dir}/META-INF
mkdist.disabled=false
platform.active=default_platform
run.classpath=\
    ${javac.classpath}:\
    ${build.classes.dir}
# Space-separated list of JVM arguments used when running the project.
# You may also define separate properties like run-sys-prop.name=value instead of -Dname=value.
# To set system properties for unit tests define test-sys-prop.name=value:
run.jvmargs=
run.modulepath=\
    ${javac.modulepath}
run.test.classpath=\
    ${javac.test.classpath}:\
    ${build.test.classes.dir}
run.test.modulepath=\
    ${javac.test.modulepath}
source.encoding=UTF-8
src.dir=src
test.src.dir=test
```

Comment: Have you consider googling "How to build executable jar file for an Apache Derby database application using Hibernate and developed in NetBeans?" - I got https://www.developer.com/java/j2me/working-with-embedded-databases-in-java.html - might be useful?

Comment: @TungstenX Yeah I've been searching for a solution for quite a while but had no luck, so I guessed I post it here in hope of a solution.

Comment: It will help if you add links to what came close to answering your question